# How can i make an asynchronous request in asp.net mvc 1.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I was wondering if I can do async requests in asp.net mvc version 1.0 app?

I saw couple examples online for mvc 2, but when i tried to create async controller in mvc 1,
i had an error.

So is it possible, or, maybe there are some libraries for that such as MVCCOntrib?

I can't use MVC 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with [this](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471)? According to the .docx in there, "The AsyncController is an experimental class...".

Good luck!

**EDIT:** Experimental at that time, asynchronous controllers are integrated into ASP.NET MVC 2.

Comment: thanks, i will take a look on it later, and if this will work, i'll accept the answer.